# How do I replace a specific piece of text in a textarea on a keyup event that gets the value of another input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I replace a specific piece of text in a textarea on a keyup event that gets the value of another input box and replaces the specific piece of text in the textarea?

HTML looks like this -

```
    <div>
       <label>test1</label>
       <input name="test_1" id="test1" type="text">

       <label>Message</label>       
       <textarea rows="2" name="textarea_2" id="textarea2">Hello [initial text] blah blah blah</textarea>   
    </div>
```

I want to replace [initial text] with whatever is put into $('#test1').val();

Thanks

Comment: Is your text area an input to something else? or is it meant to be a read-only part of your page?

Comment: It's just a normal textarea with default text already in and the user is able to change the text inside the textarea so it is NOT read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store the string to replace in var:

```
var lastStr = "[initial text]";

$("#test1").keyup(function() {
    var val = $("textarea").val();
    $("textarea").val(val.replace(lastStr, $("#test1").val()));
    lastStr = $("#test1").val(); // update last str to replace.
});
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k9uG4/1/**

**UPDATE:**

I find the previous example its not safe, Because it replaces all Match char's in Entire area.
this example Replaces only the specific piece we want:

```
var lastStr = "[initial text]";
var startIndex = $("textarea").val().indexOf(lastStr);

$("#test1").keyup(function() {
    var oldVal = $("textarea").val();
    // get all the text before
    var firstPart = oldVal.substring(0, startIndex);
    // get the piece we want And replace it
    var midPart = oldVal.substr(startIndex, lastStr.length).replace(lastStr, $("#test1").val());
    // get all the text after
    var lastPart = oldVal.substring(startIndex + lastStr.length, oldVal.length);

    $("textarea").val( firstPart + midPart +lastPart );
    lastStr = $("#test1").val();
});
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k9uG4/6/**

Comment: Thanks man, I tried something very but I didn't store that lastStr var which is where I think I was going wrong.